# Black stripe at the edge of subfigure

Tags: subfloats

I am using the subfigure to put two figures by each other. There is a black stripe at the right side of output figure which I am not sure how to remove it without changing the size of my subfigure. Here is the code I am using (just important parts are mentioned for the sake of clarity)

```
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.4\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[trim = 30mm 0mm 30mm 15mm, clip,scale=0.2]{c.jpg}
    \end{subfigure}
    ~~~\hfill
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.4\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[trim = 42mm 0mm 35mm 15mm, clip,scale=0.2]{co.jpg}
    \end{subfigure}
    \hfill
\end{figure}
```

Output is this

[image]

Comment: do you have `draft` mode on?

Comment: No. It should be a final output.

Comment: best you provide a complete MWE. there might be something interfering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two main suggestions:

- Remove the second `\hfill` instruction. (And, remove the redundant `\centering` instruction.)
- Replace the two instances of `scale=0.2` with `width=\linewidth`. If that makes the graphs look too small in your opinion, consider changing both instances of `{0.4\textwidth}` to `{0.45\textwidth}`.

  In your screenshot, both subfigure captions -- "`(a)`" and "`(b)`" -- are not centered below the respective graphs. This strongly suggests that the graphs are quite a bit wider than `0.4\textwidth`. That's why I'm suggesting you replace the sizing directive `scale=0.2` with `width=\linewidth`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[demo]{article} % remove 'demo' option in real document
\usepackage{graphicx,subcaption}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.45\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[trim = 30mm 0mm 30mm 15mm, clip,
                         width=\linewidth]{c.jpg}
    \end{subfigure}
    \hfill
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.45\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[trim = 42mm 0mm 35mm 15mm, clip,
                         width=\linewidth]{co.jpg}
    \end{subfigure}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another possible cause is that you are editing in draft mode. Removing draft option might eliminate the black stripe at the end.

Comment: Is there any other reason besides the draft mode? Maybe a package? I have the same problem but none of the answers solve it for me.